# Proving that the complex function $z^n$ is continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

To prove that $f(z)=z^n$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$ is continuous in $\mathbb{C}$, I know that we need:

Given $\varepsilon>0,\, \exists\, \delta>0$ such that if $\left|z-z_0\right|<\delta$, then $\left|z^n-z_0^n\right|<\varepsilon$.

I'm confused as to where to go from here.

I've tried using the triangle inequality to show

$$\left|z^n-z_0^n\right|\leq\left|z^n\right|-\left|z_0^n\right|=\left|z\right|^n-\left|z_0\right|^n=(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}-(x_0^2+y_0^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}$$

but I'm 1) not sure if that's totally correct and 2) if it is, I'm not sure how to use it to choose $\delta$.

Comment: $|z^n-z_{0}^n| \leq |z^n|-|z_{0}^n|$ is not true.

Comment: The inequality "$|z^n - z_0^n|\le |z^n| - |z_0^n|$" is incorrect. The $\le$ needs to be changed to $\ge$ for it to be an application of the reverse triangle inequality. Otherwise, the $-$ should become a $+$ on the RHS, by the triangle inequality.

Comment: Would $\dots\leq\left|z_0\right|^2-\left|z\right|^2$ be correct?

Comment: I think it is easier to prove that the product of continuous functions is continuous. The result then follows by induction.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm required to use $\varepsilon-\delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|z^n-z_{0}^n|=|(z-z_0)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}z_0+.....+z_0^{n-1})| \leq |z-z_0||z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}z_0+.....+z_0^{n-1}| $

As, $|z-z_0|<\delta \implies |z|=|z-z_0+z_0|< |z-z_0|+|z_0|=\delta+|z_0|$

$|z^n-z_{0}^n| \leq |z-z_0|(|z|^{n-1}+|z|^{n-2}|z_0|+.....+|z_0|^{n-1})$

$|z^n-z_{0}^n| \leq \delta((\delta+|z_0|)^{n-1}+(\delta+|z_0|)^{n-2}|z_0|+.....+|z_0|^{n-1}) $

You can choose $\delta$ accordingly to get $|z^n-z_{0}^n|< \epsilon$

However, you can also say that $z^n$ is continuous by the fact that it is the product of continuous function $z$ (n times)(Using Induction).

Comment: $\delta$ may depend on $\varepsilon$ and $z_0$, but must not depend on $z$.

Comment: @Martin Could you check if I am wrong?

Comment: It might still be difficult for the OP (who apparently is a beginner in this topic) to see  how to choose $\delta$ *explictly*, but yes, I can see nothing wrong anymore.

Comment: @Martin, Is it possible to simplify further to get $\delta$ in a neater fashion ?